# Voximplant: Error 480: Destination number is unavailable

Tags: voximplant

I am trying to make a PTSN call via Voximplant platform and i keep getting error with code 480, "Destination number is unavailable". Why am i keep getting it?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the destination number is not available. The reason can also be some provider restrictions.